# Can Mathematica resume the data that has been completely closed/quit?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, recreational-mathematics

Imagine that I run these four simple plots on a PC and then close and quit Mathematica, say the notebook file name is NOTE1

```
p0=Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,10}]
p1=Plot[Cos[x],{x,0,10}]
p2=Plot[Tan[x],{x,0,10}]
p3=Plot[Cot[x],{x,0,10}]
```

My question: after that, is it possible to open that file (NOTE1) on another PC and resume the process by running only `Show[{p0,p1,p2,p3}]` without running $\{p0,p1,p2,p3\}$ first?

---

P.S.1. I have tried it and normally it does not happen and I have to run all the plots $\{p0,p1,p2,p3\}$ first; I thought maybe there are ways (or codes) that I am not aware of them that make such situations possible.

P.S.2. The reason is that I have to run these two parts separately on two different computers since I need some extra software that cannot be installed on them.

Comment: You can export the plots and import them. I think it should work

Comment: If the plots are in output cells maybe you can just copy paste the plots themselves

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Iconize` but you need to do copy & paste, i.e. run

```
p0 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}];
p1 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}];
p2 = Plot[Tan[x], {x, 0, 10}];
p3 = Plot[Cot[x], {x, 0, 10}];
Iconize[{p0, p1, p1, p2}]
```

> [*output*]

In a new notebook copy & paste [*output*] onto end of `{p0, p1, p2, p3} =` as

```
{p0, p1, p2, p3} = [output];
```

That line is all a notebook needs to initialise variables, wherever it is.

For more automated processes consider Export, Import, Save etc.

Comment: For pre-Iconize versions (v.11) this does similar: `With[{x=Compress[{p0,p1,p1,p2}]}, Interpretation["<<Compressed Data>>", Uncompress[x]]]`

Answer (score 7):

In notebook A, do

```
p0 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}];
p1 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}];
p2 = Plot[Tan[x], {x, 0, 10}];
p3 = Plot[Cot[x], {x, 0, 10}];    
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]        
DumpSave["my_variables.mx", {p0, p1, p2, p3}]
```

Close Mathematica. All the variables are now in the file "my_variables.mx" in same folder as the above notebook. Email/send this file to anyone. On the new pc, they will open new Mathematica session and type

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
Get["my_variables.mx"]
```

And now those variables that were saved in the file are known to current notebook. No need to re-evaluate the code that generated them.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Reference https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DumpSave.html